# CSS :hover not showing

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu that has drop downs that should work. I have built drop down menus before, as well as worked with several CSS hover effects in the past. This menu is driving me crazy.

I have researched other CSS `:hover` and CSS menu issues here on Stack Overflow, and it seems that the issue is mainly getting the CSS elements in the correct order, however, I am still not understanding where my problem is, and what I'm doing wrong with the ordering.

Here is my CSS:

```
.megamenu>li>.megapanel{position:absolute;display:none;background:#ffffff;box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #777; width:100.2%;top:33px;left:0px;z-index:99;padding:20px 30px 20px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}

.megamenu>li>.megapanel:hover{display:block;}
```

I have tried different combinations on the css classes, as well as only using the `.megapanel` and `.megapanel:hover`.

When I refresh my browser and hover over the menu, nothing happens. When I load the dev tools (in Chrome) it doesn't show the `:hover` CSS in the CSS list. I'm totally lost.

Here is the piece of affected HTML code:

```
<ul class="megamenu skyblue">
        <li><a class="color1" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="grid"><a class="color2" href="#">Our Dogs</a>
            <div class="megapanel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <div class="h_nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="sires.php">Males</a></li>
                                <li><a href="toy-females.php">Toy Females</a></li>
                                <li><a href="females-mini.php">Mini Females</a></li>
                                <li><a href="upcoming.php">Upcoming</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ref.php">Reference</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.colorcountryaussies.com/pedigrees/pp_search.htm" target="_blank">Pedigrees</a></li>
                                <li><a href="past.php">Past Puppies</a></li>
                            </ul>   
                        </div>                          
                    </div></div></div></li>
```

I realize I did not finish off the HTML here, my menu is very long and I did not want to put more than necessary in here. I'm sure the solution is very simple and I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: You have it set to `display:none;` by default and then you are setting `display:none;` again on hover, what are you expecting to happen? The element is being hidden initially so there's nothing to hover anyway.

Comment: both hover and normal form display:none??

Comment: sorry for that. In my code it is set to block. I copied and pasted the same line into Stackoverflow to avoid writing twice and forgot to change that.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle ?

Comment: Im open to anything that will work. Im not a javascript dev. however.. but id be willing to do anything to make it work. Im still interested in understanding why the css isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hover something that has `display:none`.

Move the hover trigger to the parent `li`

```
.megamenu > li >.megapanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #777;
  width: 100.2%;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.megamenu>li:hover >.megapanel {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.megamenu > li {
  position: relative;
}
.megamenu > li >.megapanel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #777;
  width: 100.2%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.megamenu > li:hover >.megapanel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu skyblue">
  <li><a class="color1" href="index.php">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="grid"><a class="color2" href="#">Our Dogs</a>
    <div class="megapanel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
          <div class="h_nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="sires.php">Males</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="toy-females.php">Toy Females</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="females-mini.php">Mini Females</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="upcoming.php">Upcoming</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="ref.php">Reference</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.colorcountryaussies.com/pedigrees/pp_search.htm" target="_blank">Pedigrees</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="past.php">Past Puppies</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: That worked. I'd never have figured that out. Thanks. Im waiting for the time limit to pass so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to show the sub-menu on hover of an element that is hidden by default, so there's nothing to actually hover.

What you want to do is show the `megapanel` div when you're hovering it's parent `li` like this:

```
.megamenu>li:hover>.megapanel{display:block;}
```

```css
.megamenu>li>.megapanel{position:absolute;display:none;background:#ffffff;box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #777; width:100.2%;top:33px;left:0px;z-index:99;padding:20px 30px 20px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}

.megamenu>li:hover>.megapanel{display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu skyblue">
    <li><a class="color1" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="grid"><a class="color2" href="#">Our Dogs</a>
        <div class="megapanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col1">
                    <div class="h_nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="sires.php">Males</a></li>
                            <li><a href="toy-females.php">Toy Females</a></li>
                            <li><a href="females-mini.php">Mini Females</a></li>
                            <li><a href="upcoming.php">Upcoming</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ref.php">Reference</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.colorcountryaussies.com/pedigrees/pp_search.htm" target="_blank">Pedigrees</a></li>
                            <li><a href="past.php">Past Puppies</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with your CSS.

Both lines have the value `display:none`

I would remove it form

```
.megamenu>li>.megapanel{position:absolute;display:none;background:#ffffff;box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #777; width:100.2%;top:33px;left:0px;z-index:99;padding:20px 30px 20px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
```